# UE4Editor-CoreUObject Triggered Breakpoint

Tags: c++, breakpoints, unreal-engine4

My game is randomly crashing sometimes and I want to try and debug it and track down the issue. Currently, when the game crashes, I see this screen and does not have any information, any idea how to fix?

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UE4 Gives the option to install debugging symbols when installing/upgrading the new version:

[image: solution]